# Regex Validator and Rad Numeric Text Box Preventing me from saving

Tags: .net, regex, validation

I have the following Regular Expression Validator-

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="targetNumValidator" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ValidationExpression="/^\d{0,7}(\.\d{0,2})?$/" ControlToValidate="txtTargetNum"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

With the following Rad Numeric Text Box-

```
<telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="txtTargetNum" MaxLength="12" NumberFormat-DecimalDigits="2" runat="server">
</telerik:RadNumericTextBox>
```

I'm trying to limit the user to entering a maximum of 12 digits always including two decimal places.

**Good Examples-**

```
123.00
123.12
1234567891.00
12345.34
```

**Bad Examples-**

```
123.222
12345678912.00
```

I believed my regular expression to successfully accomplish this goal, but whenever I go to save the value through my save button it stalls out due to the regex. If I leave the field blank the save button still works fine, so I know it's being caused by the regex.

Comment: why is `1234567891.00` a bad example?

Comment: Whoops, forgot a digit. I updated the examples. Thanks

Comment: how about this? [`^\d{1,10}\.\d{2}$`](https://regex101.com/r/1vrOT7/3), `{,}` denotes the character multiplier so in your case at the start you needed any digit to appear 1 to 10 times which is achieved by `\d{1,10}`, then followed by an escaped dot `\.`, and then any another digit but this time exactly two of those, hence the `\d{2}`.

Comment: @harristyle you should post this as an answer, since it solves OPs problem ;)

Comment: I do not think regex delimiters are necessary here, `/` should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

I tried harristyle's regex, which I ended up going with after making a small tweak to it. Due to the rad numeric text box automatically adding a decimal place and two zeros if I entered a number such as 1234, which would result in the text box showing 1234.00. I had to make the decimal place and rest of the string optional.  When I save the data the decimal values are still included either way.

This is the expression I used-

```
^\d{1,10}\.?\d{2}$
```